# function of independent random variables

Tags: stochastic-calculus, statistical-inference

I have following question:
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then are $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ independent as well, for any real function $g$?

Comment: Is your question whether or not this is true (it is true), or are you looking for a proof?

Comment: looking proof..

Comment: Simply write down the definition of independent random variables and see if you can apply it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ is measurable, the answer is yes (note that otherwise, we do not even know whether $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ and random variables). Note that, for every pairs of Borel sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbf R$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P\bigl(g(X)\in A, g(Y)\in B\bigr)
  &=  \P(X \in g^{-1}[A], Y \in g^{-1}[B])\\
  &= \P(X \in g^{-1}[A])\P(Y \in g^{-1}[B])\\
  &= \P\bigl(g(X) \in A\bigr)\P\bigl(g(Y) \in B\bigr).
\end{align*}
Hence, $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.